# In C# Coded UI is there a way to wait for a control to be clickable

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

In coded ui there is a way to wait for a control to exist using `UITestControl.WaitForControlExist(waitTime);`. Is there a way to wait for a control to not exist?
The best way I could think of is to create an extension method like this:

```
public static bool WaitForControlClickable(this UITestControl control, int waitTime = 10000)
    {
        Point p;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < waitTime)
        {
            if (control.TryGetClickablePoint(out p))
            {
                return true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        return control.TryGetClickablePoint(out p);
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Also I am looking for a way to do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

So what WaitForControlExists actually does is to call the public WaitForControlPropertyEqual, something like:

```
return this.WaitForControlPropertyEqual(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Exists, true, timeout);
```

Your helper can instead call:

```
 public bool WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual(string propertyName,
                object propertyValue, int millisecondsTimeout)
```

Also, as Kek points out, there is a WaitForControlNotExist public method.

Note that they all seem to be using the same helper (also public):

```
 public static bool WaitForCondition<T>(T conditionContext, Predicate<T> conditionEvaluator, int millisecondsTimeout)
```

this helper essentially does a Thread.Sleep on the current thread, pretty much as you do it.

Comment: Sorry for channging the question on you but as useful as this answer for what I originally asked there is no clickable property that I know of so I can't wait for it.

Comment: I would say to look in that assembly and see how all these methods are implemented (use a reflector tool). They all seem to point in the same general direction of what you did.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to wait for a specific length of time, you can add to your test:

```
Playback.Wait(3000);
```

with the time in milliseconds.

Comment: Can you explain why `Playback.Wait(500);` would be preferred over the `Thread.Sleep(500);` that the code in the question already uses?

Comment: According to MSDN, Playback.Wait() lets you cancel playback before the end of the wait whereas sleep might not or throw exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131072.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a family of `WaitForControl...()` methods, including the `WaitForControlNotExist()` method.

The full set of these `Wait...` methods is:

```
WaitForControlEnabled()
WaitForControlExist()
WaitForControlNotExist()
WaitForControlPropertyEqual()
WaitForControlPropertyNotEqual()
WaitForControlReady()
```

There are also the `WaitForCondition()` and `WaitForControlCondition()` methods that can be used to wait for more complicated conditions.